# Convert array of integers to bitmap and display in PictureBox (windows Forms C++/CLR)

Tags: c++, windows, forms, clr

I am developing a windows Forms application, with C++/CLR.

I have an array of integers, let's say `int img_array[64][64];`. This 2D array contains values of a 64x64 pixels image. I need to display this array in a Picture box and I am trying to find a way to convert it into a `Bitmap^ bmp;` type, so that I can finally execute `pictureBox1->Image = bmp;`.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: what have you done so far? where are you stuck?

Comment: can you split the task in logical steps? for example: 1) construct an empty bmp object with the right size 2) loop over all the pixels 3) transform the int from the double arrays to a Color 4) set the color to the pixel.

Comment: At the moment I just have the array `img_array[64][64]` filled with pixel values. I can successfully display an image if I point to a .bmp file saved on the hard disk. What I exactly need is the code to perform a conversion from a array of integers (`int img_array[64][64]`) to a `Bitmap^ bmp` type, so that I can pass the bitmap variable to the picturebox and display it. It is just a matter of type conversion but up to now all sources I found on the internet haven't been able to solve my issue. Thank you very much